# Is it possible to use a compressor/datastructure that optimizes for multiple files having repeated content?

Tags: file, data-structures, dataset, compression

I do not know much about the internals of compression algorithms but from what I understand, most of the time the compressor does better when there are repeated characters(for text files).

I have a requirement where we would like to handle a large number of medium to large text files (approx 200Mb max size), the general case would be much smaller though say 1-20Mb,
there may be a need to search through thousands of such files too.

I was looking for a way to :

1. Come up with an on-disk data structure that allows to store contents of those files in a dense manner. (filesystems/folder structure/ alternate file types anything is okay).

This, I believe will help in searching too.

2. Compress those files using a compression algorithm that takes into account the huge number of content repetition **between the files**, most of the files are expected to contain the same contents(each file comes from a different machine so can't prevent duplication in the source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use tar and xz to make a .tar.xz archive, using a high compression option for xz.

What this does for your application is first, to compress across files since tar effectively concatenates the files (with a small header between them), where then xz treats that result as a single stream.

Second, xz looks for matching data as far back as its window size, looking for matching sequences of bytes. A high compression option will permit xz to look further back, across two or more, maybe many more, of your files. Here are the xz preset options:

```
                 Preset   DictSize   CompCPU   CompMem   DecMem
                   -0     256 KiB       0        3 MiB    1 MiB
                   -1       1 MiB       1        9 MiB    2 MiB
                   -2       2 MiB       2       17 MiB    3 MiB
                   -3       4 MiB       3       32 MiB    5 MiB
                   -4       4 MiB       4       48 MiB    5 MiB
                   -5       8 MiB       5       94 MiB    9 MiB
                   -6       8 MiB       6       94 MiB    9 MiB
                   -7      16 MiB       6      186 MiB   17 MiB
                   -8      32 MiB       6      370 MiB   33 MiB
                   -9      64 MiB       6      674 MiB   65 MiB
```

So `-9` will look back as far as 64 MB, covering a few or several of your typical file sizes of 1-20 MB. It won't be able to look across a 200 MB file.

More advanced options can specify even larger windows, up to 1.5 GB. Though that can eat up several GB of RAM while compressing, so use with care to keep the performance reasonable.